# juntar 3 queries en 1

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Después de darle mil vueltas a mi problema, a mi E/R que tenía supuestamente mal montado. No ha sido así, solo necesitaba crear una consulta adecuada, pero me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Tengo esta consulta:

```
 Select * 
FROM contratan c
RIGHT join asistencia a
ON a.usuario = c.usuario
RIGHT JOIN actuacion ac
ON a.codAsistencia = ac.asistencia
WHERE c.usuario = 17
AND c.codContrato in (select MAX(codContrato) from contratan where usuario = 17)
order by c.usuario
```

Esta consulta, me hace un histórico de todos los datos referenciados a ese usuario. pero también necesito  calcular los minutos restantes que le queda a ese usuario en su bono. Lo haría con esta otra consulta:

```
Select sum(minutos) FROM bonos, contratan where contratan.bono = bonos.codBono and contratan.usuario = 17
```

pero también necesito consultar los minutos que se han empleado en cada asistencia, lo hago con esta otra consulta.

```
Select sum(tiempoEmpleado) FROM actuacion, asistencia where actuacion.asistencia = asistencia.codAsistencia and asistencia.usuario = 17
```

La pregunta es, como podría en la primera queri, añadir estas otras dos¿??. Esto para que es¿? es para hacer un histórico completo del usuario, lo que compra, los minutos que le quedan, en que ha gastado esos minutos y las asistencias que ha solicitado.

He intentado con subconsultas en el select, pero no lo consigo... Agradezco toda ayuda. Adjunto la estructura de mi base de datos:

**Tabla users:**

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nif` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_verified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `perfil` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'usuario',
  `telefono` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `nif`, `nombre`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `direccion`, `perfil`, `telefono`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, '45921676z', 'David Serrano Alonso', 'daviserraalonso@gmail.com', NULL, '$2y$10$nZcz5O3MaE/F/ML0QSC7M.1/fe.6QYdd11Faa1Wnsh.E4TiZR3xcW', NULL, 'usuario', 652138927, NULL, '2020-11-20 09:19:46', '2020-11-20 09:19:46'),
(2, '45921676z', 'Admin', 'daviserraalonso@hotmail.com', '2020-11-20 10:29:35', '$2y$10$wxOoOy1hlc8JYnozGKy.ReNwT3Q24akiltSyfrGYJ39wjud72lH7a', NULL, 'tecnico', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

**Tabla contratan**

```
--
-- Base de datos: `bonosat`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `contratan`
--

CREATE TABLE `contratan` (
  `codContrato` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `bono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tiempoRestanteBono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `bonoSolicitado` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tiempoSolicitado` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `activo` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `contratan`
--

INSERT INTO `contratan` (`codContrato`, `fecha`, `bono`, `tiempoRestanteBono`, `bonoSolicitado`, `tiempoSolicitado`, `activo`, `usuario`) VALUES
(11, '2020-11-23 11:38:20', 6, 10, 1, 30, 0, 1);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `contratan`
--
ALTER TABLE `contratan`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codContrato`),
  ADD KEY `contratan_usuario_foreign` (`usuario`),
  ADD KEY `contratan_bono_foreign` (`bono`),
  ADD KEY `contratanBonoSoli_bono` (`bonoSolicitado`);
```

**Bonos**

```
    CREATE TABLE `bonos` (
  `codBono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `minutos` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `precio` double(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `bonos`
--

INSERT INTO `bonos` (`codBono`, `tipo`, `minutos`, `precio`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, '1/2H', 30, 20.00, NULL, NULL),
(2, '1H', 60, 40.00, NULL, NULL),
(3, '5H', 300, 175.00, NULL, NULL),
(4, '10H', 600, 330.00, NULL, NULL),
(5, '24H', 1200, 600.00, NULL, NULL),
(6, '10Min', 10, 9.00, NULL, NULL);
```

**asistencia**

```
CREATE TABLE `asistencia` (
  `codAsistencia` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `mensaje` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pendiente',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `asistencia`
--

INSERT INTO `asistencia` (`codAsistencia`, `fecha`, `mensaje`, `usuario`, `estado`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(2, '2020-11-23 11:25:29', 'Prueba Histórico', 1, 'pendiente', NULL, NULL),
(3, '2020-11-23 12:32:03', 'prueba', 1, 'pendiente', NULL, NULL);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `asistencia`
--
ALTER TABLE `asistencia`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codAsistencia`),
  ADD KEY `asistencia_usuario_foreign` (`usuario`);
```

**Al ejecutar mi primera query**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si añado las otras dos consultas:

```
Select (Select sum(minutos)FROM bonos, contratan where contratan.bono = bonos.codBono and contratan.usuario = 17), (Select sum(tiempoEmpleado) FROM actuacion, asistencia where actuacion.asistencia = asistencia.codAsistencia and asistencia.usuario = 17) 
FROM contratan c 
RIGHT join asistencia a ON a.usuario = c.usuario 
RIGHT JOIN actuacion ac ON a.codAsistencia = ac.asistencia 
WHERE c.usuario = 17 
AND c.codContrato in (select MAX(codContrato) from contratan where usuario = 17) order by c.usuario
```

El resultado de unir estos dos select, es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, me duplica los datos, y a parte, bueno, no me saca los otros datos que necesito, pero eso es ir añadiendo las columnas que necesito, lo que necesito es ir viendo el tiempo empleado por actuación y el tiempo restante del bono después

**Ejecución base de datos**

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d2b7ce320ee089b6cdb85770f397843)

Comment: ¿Ya probaste agregar esos 3 selects en el principal?

Comment: @BetaM si, ya probé. Pero quizás no lo estoy haciendo bien como sería?? De todas formas no se si habría una mejor forma de hacer eso

Comment: como probaste agregarlo?

Comment: no creo que sea la mejor idea, pero puedes hacer vistas y unirlas tal vez

Comment: gracias a todos por responder @gbianchi voy a ponerlo en seguida. El problema que me daba es que me duplicaba los datos, es decir, me sumaba los dos resultados.

Comment: @BetaM ahí he añadido las dos salidas de las consultas, como se puede ver, al unir las dos, me hace una suma, es como si recorriera dos veces. Lo que necesito es ir sacando el tiempo empleado por actuación y el tiempo restante del bono por actuación. Pensé en hacerlo como campos calculados, de echo esas dos consultas, hacen eso. He añadido más info a mi pregunta

Comment: He añadido, un enlace a una web, donde se pueden ver los resultados con mis datos actuales @gbianchi

Comment: Otra vez, ese query esta bien... que traiga 2 registros no es incorrecto... porque en los joins originales te devuelve 2 registros! porque lo otro deberia devolverte 1 solo? en ese caso, tu pregunta es, este query me devuelve un registro de mas.. porque_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregar los subquerys a tu query, es solamente agregar las consultas como columnas

```
SELECT *,
(Select sum(minutos) 
FROM bonos, contratan 
where contratan.bono = bonos.codBono and contratan.usuario = 17),
(Select sum(tiempoEmpleado) 
FROM actuacion, asistencia 
where actuacion.asistencia = asistencia.codAsistencia and asistencia.usuario = 17)
FROM contratan c
RIGHT join asistencia a ON a.usuario = c.usuario
RIGHT JOIN actuacion ac ON a.codAsistencia = ac.asistencia
WHERE c.usuario = 17
  AND c.codContrato in ( SELECT MAX(codContrato) 
                         FROM contratan 
                         WHERE usuario = 17 )
ORDER BY c.usuario
```

Ahora, cuel es el problema? si la query original devolvia dos registros, la query nueva va a devolver dos registros, y los datos que va a traer son siempre los mismos, ya que la unica relacion entre ellos es el usuario.

Tene en cuenta que el numero 17 se puede reemplazar por cualquier variable.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @gbianchi el problema es que necesito, la suma por actuación, tanto del tiempo por actuación, como restante del bono cada vez que se aplique una actuación. Voy a probar lo que tú dices

Comment: Entonces, como te dije en su momento, falta una relacion en algun lado... este query te devuelve lo que queres... si hay mas registros, cosa que todavia no estas pensando, falta la relacion entre los mismos...

Comment: he encontrado  un posible solución en vez de otra relación. Lo tengo todo en contratan, asistencia y actuaciones. La solución es ir calculando los tiempos por actuación. Ya que en la actuación, tengo el tiempo empleado, y luego para sacar a que bono pertenece cada actuación, es comparando las fechas, si una actuación es inferior a la de una contratación, pues pertenece a otro bono. Eso es lo que pretendo hacer. De ahí mis sum y eso... El problema es que no me calcula el tiempo por actuación. Es decir, actuacion x minutos empleados x minutos restantes al bono (la operacion)

Comment: @scorpions y por eso te dije que te faltaba una tabla.. calcular todo, cada vez que hagas el query, no va a escalar en el futuro... va a tardar horas en ejecutarse... toda esa informacion, que tenes al momento de hacerlo, deberias guardarla...

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer uniones como esta yo el método que uso es agregar subconsultas en los join, y luego aplicarla en el select.

```
Select *
    , restantes.minutos
    , empleados.minutos
FROM contratan c
    RIGHT join asistencia a ON a.usuario = c.usuario
    RIGHT JOIN actuacion ac ON a.codAsistencia = ac.asistencia
    LEFT JOIN (
        Select contratan.usuario, sum(minutos)  minutos
        FROM bonos, contratan 
        where contratan.bono = bonos.codBono
            and contratan.usuario = 17
    ) restantes ON C.usuario = restantes.usuario
    LEFT JOIN (
       Select asistencia.usuario, sum(tiempoEmpleado) tiempoEmpleado
       FROM actuacion, asistencia
       where actuacion.asistencia = asistencia.codAsistencia 
        and asistencia.usuario = 17
    ) empleados ON C.usuario = empleados.usuario
WHERE c.usuario = 17
    AND c.codContrato in (select MAX(codContrato) from contratan where usuario = 17)
order by c.usuario
```

Deje las consultas en un LEFT JOIN, por que no se si deben existir los registros en las tablas de bonos y actuación, de cualquier forma los puedes cambiar.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. Pero al intentar ejecutar la consulta, no encuentra restantes.minutos, ni empleados.minutos. Los minutos restantes, debería de ser calculado. Ya que es el tiempo restante que le queda al bono del usuario. El tiempo empleado, si se puede sacar por la actuación, pero si hacemos una suma de los minutos empleados y lo restamos al tiempoRestante del bono, se podría ir calculando en cada actuación el tiempo que le va quedando al usuario en su bono, que es lo que pretendo